# how to master wordpress theming?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, xhtml, themes

I have recently finished up learning PHP/MySQL,css3,xhtml and Photoshop.And now i want to create themes for WordPress.So please suggest me some ideas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by downloading some of the popular [themes](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/), (such as [cutline](http://cutline.tubetorial.com/)) and looking through the source.

It's essential to understand the [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), and the [widget system](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins/WordPress_Widgets_Api).

Keep the [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/) and [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) docs handy (there's a function for most things you could want to do).

Comment: thanks Meleyal.where i can learn more about creating  theme-option panel

Comment: Have a look at any theme or plugin that provides it's own options / UI. Wordpress has functions for creating your own pages / forms in the backend + a way to save the options in the db.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read [Digging into wordpress](http://digwp.com/) by Chris Coyer and Jeff Star.
It's a great guide for learning wordpress and it also provides a great section dedicated to wordpress theming.